# extracting from specific row a set of values through string

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

Would be very thankful for any help.

How to make the first row of row[0] where there is Breakdown and the dates to be headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add new column name to list, e.g. `Col1`:

```
math = [['Jason',100,35],
            ['Alice',87.89,100],
            ['Mary',68,0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(math, columns=['Name','Grade', 'Col1'])
print (df)
   Name   Grade  Col1
0  Jason  100.00    35
1  Alice   87.89   100
2   Mary   68.00     0
```

Then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter by `Name` and by column name:

```
a = df.loc[df['Name'] == 'Alice', 'Grade']
print (a)
1    87.89
Name: Grade, dtype: float64
```

Then for first matched value use `next` with `iter`:

```
val = next(iter(a), 'no match')
print (val)
87.89
```

...what should be used for return default value if no match:

```
a = df.loc[df['Name'] == 'William', 'Grade']
print (a)
Series([], Name: Grade, dtype: float64)

val = next(iter(a), 'no match')
print (val)
no match
```

Comment: I also extract tables form other teachers and in their data frame the first row contains 0 1 2 3 4 as index and the second row contained the name and dates. How to make the second row to be the index row or the first row?

Comment: @Gunel - Can you change data of sample?

Comment: I want to say that I might scrap data frame for other sources (internet) as statics to compare performance and the table has 'Name','Grade', 'Final' located on the second row, in the first row it has the number given for columns like 1,2,3,4. How ro replace the first row and make the second row the header so that I can implement what you wrote in answer?

Comment: @Gunel - Can you show data which cannot be used `df = pd.DataFrame(math, columns=['Name','Grade', 'Final'])` ?

Comment: This is library that gives such data frame, so I put the pic of the first 2 rows to get what I mean. I want Breakdown and and dates to be headers, but the library makes them as part of the tables not headers

Comment: I only insert the library and write df and it gives me the table which look like the above I put and the rest are names of student I can't put I just put the first 2 rows. Would be thankful if you could help how to remove the first row and make the second the header

Comment: @Gunel - How is created DataFrame?

Comment: as I said it is library that we incorporate and then just write tables name for example df it give ready data. But it is pandas data frame

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204872/discussion-between-jezrael-and-gunel).